# Posting data from ajax to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Trying to send a post request from ajax to php.

I did many trial and errors based from the answers including making sure that the "type" is set to post, specifying "dataType", correct "url". I think I miss something important but I can't figure out what it is.

**main.php**

```php
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".editContact").on("click", function(){
        let dataID = $(this).attr("data-id");
        console.log(dataID);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'functions/phonebook.php',
            dataType: "text",
            data:{data:dataID}              

         });

        });
    });
</script>
```

**functions/phonebook.php**

```php
if(isset($_POST["data"])){
        $res = array($data=>var_dump($_POST["data"]));
    }
    else{
        $res ='null';
    }
```

Then print the $res variable containing the dataID from ajax to my html element in **main.php**

```php
<label class="m-label-floating">Contact name <?php echo $res; ?> </label>
```

The console.log in my main.php prints the data what I want to send in ajax but when I try to send the dataID to my phonebook.php, I get a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$res = array($data=>var_dump($_POST["data"]));
```

You are using [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) the wrong way.

From the docs:

> This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value. Arrays and objects are explored recursively with values indented to show structure.

This function does not return any value, so, in your case, `$data=>var_dump($_POST["data"])` will always be null.

What you need to is:

```
$res = array($data => $_POST["data"]);
```

Comment: I see, i did the changes based from your answer, but I still get a null value. I suspect the dataID in ajax is not posted successfully to my php file.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your ajax call. You can try to `echo $_POST['data']` in the beginning of your PHP script in to check if the value was sent.

Comment: tried `$res = echo $_POST['data']; `  then print out in main. html using `echo $res; ` still no data printed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending data to a different page altogether and need to use jquery / JS to do it, it might be simpler to send via window replace:

```
 window.location.replace(...)
```

If you need to stay on the same page, you might want to include a success function in your ajax query, as this will return to the page you are calling from:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'functions/phonebook.php',
        data:{data:dataID},                
        success: function (html) {
             // do your HTML replace / add stuff  here
        },
     });
```